How to display value retrieved from column CMDB

How to display value retrieved from column CMDB
I want the column business service on the left to return the value based on the CMDB table
How can I achieve to do that?



IP address
business service
business owner




10.10.10.10
SFTP Server
Khai


10.10.10.20
WAF
Julie


10.90.40.200
UCCS
Shairil


192.168.10.11
WorkSafe
Aditya




If you have Microsoft 365, try with XLOOKUP function - Microsoft Support

try in cell E3 (assuming your first row with a formula will be row 3):
=xlookup(D3,M:M,I:I,"not found")

In words: look for the value of D3 in column M and when found, return the value of that row from column I. If no match is found, return "not found".
If you use an older Excel version without Xlookup, you can use Index/Match
=Index(I:I,match(D3,M:M,0))

For either formula, copy down in column E.

Seriously? Begging for an accept the minute you post the answer? Why are you begging for an accept at all? That's inappropriate conduct. If the user finds your answer resolves the problem, they are free to accept it and/or upvote.

@KenWhite Not sure what the issue is. I've been posting that comment to my answers for at least ten years without any issue. I only post this comment if the OP is a brand new user and may not yet have seen the tour. I'm not "begging" for an answer. I am inviting them to feed back if the answer doesn't meet their needs and I'm giving them the information to accept the answer as described in the tour. What's wrong with that? Nobody has ever given me negative feedback on that. Until you today.

First, as the comment is not asking for additional details or responding to a request for the same, it's useless noise (and is actually flaggable as such). Second, while the new user might not know about accepting today, if they stay here, they'll learn eventually and come back and accept it. Third, begging for reputation (especially as a relatively high rep user) is just demeaning yourself. If you've earned the rep and the user wants  to provide it, that's their choice - that's how SO works.

And to address "new user and may not yet have seen the tour", this poster has the badge for having done so, and if you think a new user hasn't done so, the proper course of action is to suggest that they go and take the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works in order to improve their experiences here. That's a much more beneficial action to take for SO than "Please give me rep by accepting my answer. Please?"

If using Microsoft 365, fill-down from first cell (available Excel 2013 and higher):
=IFNA(
    XLOOKUP(TRIM(D3), TRIM(K:K), I:J),
    IFNA(
        XLOOKUP(TRIM(D3), TRIM(L:L), I:J),
        XLOOKUP(TRIM(D3), TRIM(M:M), I:J, "not found")
    )
)

preferred version, only in the first cell (convoluted?, will try to come up with a scalable one later… :):
=LAMBDA(ip_addresses, from_CMDB,
    LET(
        from_CMDB, TRIM(from_CMDB),
        ip_addresses, TRIM(ip_addresses),
        service_and_owner, CHOOSECOLS(from_CMDB, 1, 2),
        lookup_ip, LAMBDA(ip_addr, col_index,
            XLOOKUP(
                ip_addr,
                CHOOSECOLS(from_CMDB, col_index),
                service_and_owner
            )
        ),
        DROP(
            REDUCE(
                "",
                ip_addresses,
                LAMBDA(business_info, ip_addr,
                    VSTACK(
                        business_info,
                        IFNA(
                            lookup_ip(ip_addr, 3),
                            IFNA(
                                lookup_ip(ip_addr, 4),
                                IFNA(
                                    lookup_ip(ip_addr, 5),
                                    "not found"
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            1
        )
    )
)(D3:D6, I3:M8)


Looking up with combining the three IP address columns:
=LAMBDA(ip_addresses, from_CMDB,
    LET(
        from_CMDB, TRIM(from_CMDB),
        lookups_combined, TOCOL(DROP(from_CMDB, , 2), , TRUE),
        ip_addresses, TRIM(ip_addresses),
        todo_1, "Use MAKEARRAY",
        service_and_owner_base, CHOOSECOLS(from_CMDB, 1, 2),
        service_and_owner, VSTACK(
            service_and_owner_base,
            service_and_owner_base,
            service_and_owner_base
        ),
        result, DROP(
            REDUCE(
                "",
                ip_addresses,
                LAMBDA(business_info, ip_addr,
                    VSTACK(
                        business_info,
                        XLOOKUP(
                            ip_addr,
                            lookups_combined,
                            service_and_owner,
                            "not found"
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            1
        ),
        result
    )
)(D3:D6, I3:M8)



Thank you, but I'm having difficulty understanding it.

XLOOKUP function - Microsoft Support Logic is the same, but the first option is perhaps easier to understand: lookup ip_addr in ABS IP, if not found XLOOKUP will return #N/A, with IFNA we can then look up in FrontEndIP and so forth. Exact lookup will fail when there are spaces at the start/end of the input - so remove such spaces with TRIM function - Microsoft Support. Hope this helps.
